# how to group-by xml nodes using xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

This is my xml

```
<hotel>
    <rooms>
        <room>
            <rates>
                <rates id="1" adult="1" child="0"><rates>
                <rates id="2" adult="2" child="0"><rates>
                <rates id="3" adult="1" child="0"><rates>
            </rates>
        </room>
        <room>
            <rates>
                <rates id="4" adult="1" child="0"><rates>
                <rates id="5" adult="2" child="0"><rates>
                <rates id="6" adult="2" child="0"><rates>
            </rates>
        </room>
    </rooms>
</hotel>
```

How to make group by based on "Adults" and "Child" using xslt 1.0

same adult and child in one rates node and the way of grouping

result i need like below,

```
<hotel>
    <rooms>
        <room>
            <rates>
                <rates id="1" adult="1" child="0"><rates>
                <rates id="3" adult="1" child="0"><rates>
                <rates id="4" adult="1" child="0"><rates>
            </rates>
        </room>
        <room>
            <rates>
                <rates id="2" adult="2" child="0"><rates>
                <rates id="5" adult="2" child="0"><rates>
                <rates id="6" adult="2" child="0"><rates>
            </rates>
        </room>
    </rooms>
</hotel>
```

Comment: Grouping in XSLT 1.0: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: i try lot can you give me a sample. because i am new in xslt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Example of Muenchian Grouping](http://xsltransform.net/6r5Gh3C)...

**XML Input** (modified to be well formed and add example of `child` values)

```
<hotel>
    <rooms>
        <room>
            <rates>
                <rates id="1" adult="1" child="0"/>
                <rates id="1A" adult="2" child="3"/>
                <rates id="2" adult="2" child="0"/>
                <rates id="3" adult="1" child="0"/>
            </rates>
        </room>
        <room>
            <rates>
                <rates id="4" adult="1" child="0"/>
                <rates id="5" adult="2" child="0"/>
                <rates id="6" adult="2" child="0"/>
                <rates id="6A" adult="2" child="3"/>
            </rates>
        </room>
    </rooms>
</hotel>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!--Group "rates" by combining the adult and child attribute values.-->
  <xsl:key name="rates" match="rates" use="concat(@adult,'|',@child)"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="rooms">
    <rooms>
      <!--
      This for-each will match the first "rates" element in each group.
      Nothing is done with the matched "rates" element; we only do this 
      to wrap the group with "room".
      -->
      <xsl:for-each select="room/rates/rates[count(.|key('rates',concat(@adult,'|',@child))[1])=1]">
        <room>
          <!--This apply-templates selects all "rates" in the group.-->
          <xsl:apply-templates select="key('rates',concat(@adult,'|',@child))"/>
        </room>
      </xsl:for-each>      
    </rooms>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<hotel>
   <rooms>
      <room>
         <rates id="1" adult="1" child="0"/>
         <rates id="3" adult="1" child="0"/>
         <rates id="4" adult="1" child="0"/>
      </room>
      <room>
         <rates id="1A" adult="2" child="3"/>
         <rates id="6A" adult="2" child="3"/>
      </room>
      <room>
         <rates id="2" adult="2" child="0"/>
         <rates id="5" adult="2" child="0"/>
         <rates id="6" adult="2" child="0"/>
      </room>
   </rooms>
</hotel>
```